# How to view other user profiles in php?

Tags: php, mysql

So for my project I am viewing the home page with

```
$userID = $_SESSION['uid'];
```

which shows my account. Now I have a search bar where shows up all the users from the database based on what the user types in matching. Now what I am stuck with is, how do a user who is logged in view other user profiles after typing in the name in the search box. I have seen a way of doing this by $_GET, but I am not getting the entire picture here.

I know there have been similar questions like this asked over here before, but my additional question is how do I get the exact user that has been typed in since there might be two users with the same name in the database.

This is my search code.

**index.php**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search_bootstrap.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" style="width: 200px;" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type a name">
```

**search_bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysql_connect("host","username","password");
    $db=mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from users where first_name LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $array[] = $row['first_name'];
    }      

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: "how do I get the exact user that has been typed in since there might be two users with the same name in the database" The usual solution is to display both and let the user pick the one they want.

Comment: yes, that's right, but say, there two users with the same name, how do I fetch the id of THAT particular user. Like I cannot do a where condition which says name=$typed_in_name. That way the query wont understand which one to find, right?

Comment: Use PDO where possible PDO stands for **"PHP Data Objects"** and is a database access layer providing a uniform method of access to multiple databases. PDO supports a wide range of databases everything from PostgreSQL, MySql, Oracle databases are also supported. Using PDO is very simple and there is a detailed tutorial over here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: Encryption and security should be your **first** priority I can not stress that enough. If you choose to handle your users sign in / sign up process please make sure that nothing goes in or out of your DB without all the necessary escaping methods and encryption methods. Try classify the how sensitive data is and use different encryption methods for data such as passwords, emails & identifiers. Alternatives to handling your users sign in / sign up systems are the Facebook, Google or Twitter login API's.

Comment: Also as an extension to @PraveenKumar comment: The original MySQL extension has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and should be replaced by the The MySQLi Extension (MySQL Improved) its pretty much the same use it like this: **"mysqli_*"**.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to wrap your input element with a form tag that sends to the show profile page:

```
<form method="post" action="./show_profile.php">
    <input type="text" style="width: 200px;" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type a name">

    <input type="submit" value="Show Profile"/>
</form>
```

and in the `show_profile.php` file do the reverse query you have done while typing:

```
$name = $_POST['typeahead'];

$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$psw = "psw";
$db_name = "dbname";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE first_name = ?";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $user, $psw);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($name));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($result) == 1)
    {
        $profile_info = $result[0];
        echo "Welcome to " . $profile_info['first_name'] . "'s personal profile page!";

        //echo others profile infos, example: echo "Age: " . $profile_info['first_name'];
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //HandleErrors
}
```

Obviously this can be done only if there is a 1 to 1 correspondence between name and users.

If, for example there are two users called Jhon, when the user is typing you can suggest both and let him choose. When he has chosen you re-do the same query but returning the id of the chosen user, and use it as `<input type="hidden" name="user_id">` value. In the php file I suggested you, you can read another param `$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];` and change the query in `$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE first_name = ? AND id = ?";`.

The result:

```
$name = $_POST['typeahead'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$psw = "psw";
$db_name = "dbname";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE first_name = ? AND id = ?";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $user, $psw);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute(array($name));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($result) == 1)
    {
        $profile_info = $result[0];
        echo "Welcome to " . $profile_info['first_name'] . "'s personal profile page!";

        //echo others profile infos, example: echo "Age: " . $profile_info['first_name'];
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    //Handle Errors
}
```

Close to your project, you have to work with Javascript in order to display the suggested (and queried) names, let the user choose, fill the hidden input value, query with Ajax,..

Have a good work!

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that I'm going to (attempt) to answer a bunch of questions in one answer so it might be quite a big answer.

> "$userID = $_SESSION['uid'];"

This is just a note but always remember before storing anything in **$_SESSION** make sure you double check (maybe even encrypt or escape) the information you are about to store and the information you have already stored.

> "how do a user who is logged in view other user profiles after typing in the name in the search box"

When it comes to "instant-searching" AJAX is your best friend
Here is a small example of "instant-searching" in JavaScript using the jQuery library.
I've also commented the script for you to make my code easier to understand.

HTML:

```
<div class="search-box-container">
  <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search..." />
</div>
<div class="results-container">
  <!-- your results go here -->
</div>
```

JavaScript(using jQuery):

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {
  $(".search-box").on("keyup", function() {
    // cache the "this" object
    var self = this,
      // this is the minimum length the search query can be
      minlen = 3,
      // cache the search query
      query = $(this).val(),
      // cache the results container
      container = $(".results-container");
    // make sure our query is at least the minimum length
    if (query.length >= minlen) {
      $.ajax({
        // the method we'll be using
        type: "POST",
        // this is the path to your PHP search script
        url: "./path/to/search.php",
        data: {
          // these are the parameters we'll be sending to PHP
          "query": query
        },
        // this is the type of response we'll be getting back (from PHP)
        dataType: "text",
        // "success" will execute when no errors happen and everything goes goed
        success: function(response) {
          // double check to make sure that we are searching using the correct query
          // also make sure that we actually have a query
          if (query == $(self).val() && query !== undefined || query !== null) {
            // overwrite the response in our container
            container.html(response);
          }
        },
        // "error" will occour when there is an error
        error: function() {
          container.html("Sorry failed to search.");
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(this, this.document, jQuery);
```

PHP:

```
# check to see if we have been given a query
if(!isset($_POST["query"])) {
  echo("No query recived.");
  exit();
}
# the name of the user the user was searching for
$name = $_POST["query"];
# the username and password of the database
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
try {
  # connect to our database
  $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yoursite_users", $user, $pass);
  # prepare and execute our query
  $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE first_name = ?");
  $query->execute(array($name));
  # fetch our results
  $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  # make sure we have at least one result
  if(count($results) > 0) {
    # you can now use any profile
    # loop through each profile
    # or even just use the first like this:
    $profile = $results[0];
    echo("Your search for: <b>\"" . $name . "\"</b> returned: <b>\"" . count($results) . "\"</b> results.");
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  # catch and handle errors here
  echo("Oops something went wrong :(");
}
```

> "but say, there two users with the same name, how do I fetch the id of THAT particular user."

Your users should have more than one identifier and when creating users make sure that the id's you assign the new user don't already exist within your database.

When your users search you should not show them results of their own page/user, you can do this by excluding results with their id, secure_id or page_id.

Here is a (simplified) example of a user entry:

```
{
  "user_id": "12-bit-primary-identifier",
  "user_sid": "32-bit-secondary-identifier",
  "user_pid": "6-bit-page-identifier",
  "user_code": "encrypted-entry-code",
  "user_validated": "0",
  "user_name": "johnny_bravo",
  "user_full_name": "john smith",
  "user_first_name": "john",
  "user_last_name": "smith"
}
```

When you have more than one identifier for each user you will still be able to confirm whether or not two users are the same you can do this by checking each id and excluding the entry you do not wish to get info from or modify.

Here is a (simplified) example of another very similar user entry:

```
{
  "user_id": "12-bit-primary-identifier",
  "user_sid": "32-bit-secondary-identifier",
  "user_pid": "6-bit-page-identifier",
  "user_code": "encrypted-entry-code",
  "user_validated": "1",
  "user_name": "superman",
  "user_full_name": "john smith",
  "user_first_name": "john",
  "user_last_name": "smith"
}
```

Now when your user searches for "john smith" you can automatically exclude the first "john smith" I.E "jhonny_bravo" using his "user_id" (which you can get with `$_SESSION["user_id"]`)

Comment: Bishwaroop, has my answer helped you? Do you mind sharing if and how you solved the problem?